How can I make sure Excel will remain connected to Bloomberg to perform spreadsheet automations?
My Python code opens Excel, runs some macros that are used on Bloomberg formulas then closes everything.
import time
import win32com.client as win32
import gc

def update_excel_and_send_email():
    excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
    excel.Visible = False  

    try:
        wb = excel.Workbooks.Open('mypath')
        wb.RefreshAll()
        time.sleep(10) 
        excel.Application.Run("Send2")

    except Exception as e:
        print("Error: " + str(e))
    finally:
        wb.Close(SaveChanges=False)
        excel.Quit()
        excel = None
        gc.collect()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    update_excel_and_send_email()

Example of the bbg formulas:

My dream goal is to run these macros without having Excel pop up on my screen. I am always connected to Bloomberg, and I also want to execute this code even if my computer is locked, thanks to a scheduler. It works for an hour or two even if my computer is locked, then randomly, all the formulas that I receive by email thanks to the macros are not updated anymore with bbg and are displayed as #N/A. I've been trying to refresh Bloomberg with formulas each time I run my macros with Excel but it doesn't work when Excel crashes.
Two observations:

When it crashes, even if I open the Excel sheet manually, every data remains N/A, thus I need to completely close Excel and open it again to refresh the formulas.
Formulas sometimes are not refreshed if Excel is in background (I wish to run all that in the background without having to wait until all the macros are done running).


Typically when you are getting information from a website... and it works for a while and then stops working - that is a good indication that the website's owners have temporarily disabled it for you as they do not want you scraping data like that. It's most common for financial sites. Did you check the website's terms to make sure it's allowed?

This is most likely happening when you open Bloomberg Anywhere on your phone or another computer, which disconnects the session on the computer where your code is running. Also, as mentioned in an answer, that is very likely to be a breach of Bloomberg's data usage policy (Desktop API data is not supposed to leave the terminal computer), but that's not why it's disconnecting.

Contrary to @braX'd comment, that's not a website but a Bloomberg API request within Excel.
You can skip Excel and use the API directly. WAPI has all details you may need (or search here for lots of content). If you really want an Excel format, export the data feed to an Excel workbook once you get the data.
That said, it's breaching the data feed addendum everyone signs when you try to distribute (email) the data. The standard API is for desktop use, which means you should not have access without being actively involved in the process of looking at the data. The connection breaks after a while for this reason (also whenever you look up stuff on your phones app). If you need automated downloads you should use data license offerings.
